# Android - Extend an image and keep scale

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I'd like to have an image (DistantImageView, ImageView from the web) with width="fill_parent" and height="wrap_content" while keeping the scale.

The image is smaller than the screen and because it comes from the web, I don't know about the proportions.

I tried

```
 <DistantImageView
        android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 />
```

It doesn't work, the image is smaller than the screen.

Thanks in advance